# VsCode debugger is going into node_modules files with docker remote

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to add a debug configuration for VsCode in a NodeJS application.

The issues I've been facing since a few days is that when I have to go inside a function, it goes into the node_modules JS code, but I actually don't need to test it.

To be more precise, here are the steps of my testing process :

- First, my breakpoint is well detected and the debbuger stop at it.

[Breakpoint detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDiAh.png)

- Then when I try to "Step Into (F11)" to watch the function, it goes inside the `/node_modules/async-listener/es6-wrapped-promise.js` file

[es6-wrapped-promise.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhdV9.png)

- I thought it would ignore the file, but VsCode debugger open it and I have to "Step Out (Shift+F11)" to go back to the function I needed to watch.
  Also, when I stepp out of it, it brings me back to the end of the function without testing each steps of it.

[Goes at the end of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw4zn.png)

My configs are the following :

- For the launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "My API debugg Config",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "restart": true,
            "port": 9229,
            "address": "localhost",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/my-api/src/",
            "remoteRoot": "/home/app/src/",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "skipFiles": [
                "/home/app/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/my-api/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried to add thoses configurations during my tests :

```json
{
"skipFiles": [
    "/home/app/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "${workspaceFolder}/my-api/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "/home/app/node_modules/async-listener/es6-wrapped-promise.js",
    "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
],
"smartStep": true,
"sourceMaps": true
}
```

- For the docker command (inside package.json)

`"dev": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --legacy-watch -P 4000 --exec node -r ts-node/register src/index.ts",`

- Using thoses versions of librairies

```json
{
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5",
}
```

- Finally the ts-config.json file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2016",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

So, How can I make the debugger not going through the node_modules source code, and instead, step into my function to test it step by step ?

I hope that I've not been to far in my explaination and that I have been enough clear putting you my issue forward.